# How to Call JavaScript functions by clicking a button and perform operations in looped textboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sum

I'm new in javascript and I want to know how to perform some math operations per row in the table by clicking the button.

The textboxes in the column "Variable" are created by a while loop, and I want to iterate the operation over two values one value from the first textbox in the array (variable 1) and the another from  the second one (variable 2) so I need to sum or substract the two numbers depending of the button.

how can I make the javascript functions to call it by clicking the button?

> In my example I have a "Case statement" getting the id from my table
>   "operations" where if the id is 1 it has to sum, 2 it has to
>   substract, 3 it has to make a multiplication.

for example I have three rows:

---

1. Indicador 1  = Variable 1 + Variable 2  ---> click the button ----> show the result of the sum.
2. Indicador 2  = Variable 3 - Variable 4  ---> click the button ----> show the result of the substraction.
3. Indicador 3  = Variable 5 * Variable 6  ---> click the button ----> show the result of the multiplication.

and so on

**You can see the table I have.**

[image: https://s7.postimg.org/fc88q2t23/tabla.jpg]

If I missed something let me know.

**This code display the table above.**

```
        <form action="ingreso-datos-exe.php" method="post"> 
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $iduser;?>"  name="iduser"/>
         <table id="tabla-registros" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
   <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Indicador</th>
          <th>Variables</th>
           <th>Result</th>
          <th>Compute Operation</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>



        <?php

        //to get the indicator's name in the first column of the table

        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkSQL)) {
                $id_indicador= $r['id_indicador'];
                $nombre= $r['nombre_indicador'];
                $id_calculo= $r['id_calculo'];
                echo $id_indicador.$nombre.'</br>'; ?>

        <td><?php echo $id_indicador.$nombre;?></td><td>
          <table>
         <tr>

        <?php   

            // To get the variable's name in the second column of the table     
            while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkSQL2)) {
                $nombre_variable= $r2['nombre_variable_medicion'];
                $idvariable= $r2['id_variablemedicion'];
                //  var_dump($r2);
                                             ?>

    <th><?php echo $nombre_variable;?></th>
    <td width=60px><input type="text" value="" class="price" name="valor[<?php echo $idvariable; ?>]"/></td> 

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_indicador;?>"  name="id_indicador[<?php echo $idvariable; ?>]"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idvariable;?>"  name="id_variable[<?php echo $idvariable; ?>]"/>

      <?php     } ?>


                        </tr>
                        <tr>

           </tr> 

          </table>

  <?php switch($id_calculo){ 

                            case '1':?>
                                <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="btnSum" value="Sum"    OnClick="fncSum();"></td>


                           <?php  break; ?>


                          <?php case '2':?>
                          <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="btnSum" value="substract" OnClick="fncSum();"></td>


                           <?php  break; ?>

                          <?php case '3':?>
                         <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="btnSum" value="multiplication" OnClick="fncSum();"></td>


                          <?php  break;
                           } ?>
                           <?php    echo '</td>'.'</tr>';
                          }
                                ?>                  



</tbody>

</table>


        </form>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="click handling code here">`, basically...

Comment: "how can I make the javascript functions to call it by clicking the button?" What exactly is "it"? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to start correctly indenting and formatting your code. It is very confusing to analyze.

Comment: @Alexandre alright I'll do it now, "it" = is the javascript function, because I do not know how to sum the looped textboxes and every "INDICADOR" has its own math operation, can you help me ?

Comment: @MarcB do you know how to make the function to sum  looped textboxes?

Comment: I have no idea what a "looped textbox" is.

Comment: If your problem is how to get to the text boxes values, I would suggest you to use a javascript library such as jQuery where you could just do something like: function sum() { var total = 0; $(".price").each(function() { total += $(this).val(); }); return total; }

Comment: @MarcB How can I sum the textboxes with the same name? because they are result of the while loop, and I want to perform math operation taking the two textboxes per indicador

Comment: @Alexandre with that function can I get only the two values per row?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean by that. You mention in your question that you want to make an operation on two text boxes, but you only seem to have have one per row?

Comment: @Alexandre sorry, I'll try to explain again, in the code I only coded  one input text, but I make a while loop to iterate one input text per "VARIABLE", as a result it display two textboxes, and I want to sum one textbox with another.

Comment: Sorry but taking too much of my time. If you have any specific coding question feel free to ask, but I'll not implement your algorithm for you. (sorry if that sounds rude) Best of luck.

Comment: @Alexandre Heeeyyy I found a solution but can you help me with the substraction please? [Look this code please](http://jsfiddle.net/w0029xuz/17/)  something is wrong with the substraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//returns parent row for the button
function getRow(el) {
    var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    return row;
}

//returns number from val1
function getVal1(row) {
    return +row.querySelector(".val1").value || 0
}

//returns number from val2
function getVal2(row) {
    return +row.querySelector(".val2").value || 0
}


//sets result
function setResult(row, val) {
    row.querySelector(".result").value = val
}

//do action
//reads action from the data-action attribute
function action() {
    var a = this.getAttribute("data-action");
    var row = getRow(this);
    var val1 = getVal1(row);
    var val2 = getVal2(row);
    var res = 0;
    switch (a) {
        case "sum":
            res = val1 + val2;
            break;
        case "substract":
            res = val1 - val2;
            break;
        case "multiplication":
            res = val1 * val2;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown action '"+a+"'");
    }
    setResult(row, res);
}

//adds click event for each btn-action elements after document loaded
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-action");
    for (var i=0; i<btns.length; i++) {
        var btn = btns[i];
        btn.addEventListener("click", action);
    }
})
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td><input class="val1"/></td>
        <td><input class="val2" /></td>
        <td><input class="result" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn-action" value="Sum" data-action="sum"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td><input class="val1" /></td>
        <td><input class="val2" /></td>
        <td><input class="result" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn-action" value="Substract" data-action="substract" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td><input class="val1" /></td>
        <td><input class="val2" /></td>
        <td><input class="result" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn-action" value="Multiplication" data-action="multiplication" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Greaaaaat it is possible to perform the operations without implementing the name of the input textbecause in my case the name is the same.  I can't doit like this res = val1 + val2; because I only have one input text, but when I use a while loop it shows two